# String ordering using fold

Tags: haskell

I'm a newbie in haskell and start to write my first small program.

The purpose: The app asks the user to input items for some categories. All inputs are stored in a Map Category [Item] (or Map String [String]). Once all categories has been fulfilled, the map is written to a file.

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map

type InputLine = IO [String]

type ItemsRegistry = Map.Map String InputLine

--main = do sequence . printValues . getInput $ ["head", "body"]

main = do
  writeFile "data.txt" ""
  putStrLn "Write the word \"stop\" to end the input"
  sequence . writeData "data.txt" . getInput $ ["B", "A"]

getInput :: [String] -> ItemsRegistry
getInput cat = foldl (\acc category -> Map.insert category (insertCategory category) acc) Map.empty cat

insertCategory :: String -> InputLine
insertCategory category = do
  putStrLn $ "Add items for category " ++ category
  insertItem []

insertItem :: [String] -> InputLine
insertItem values = do
  x <- getLine
  case x of "stop" -> return values
            x -> insertItem (x:values)

writeData ::  String -> ItemsRegistry -> [IO ()]
writeData path data_ = [ writeLine path k (Map.lookup k data_) |  k <- Map.keys data_ ]

-- filepath category lineOfItems
writeLine :: String -> String -> Maybe InputLine -> IO ()
writeLine path category (Just line) = line >>= (\words -> appendFile path $ formatLine category (unwords words))  
writeLine path category Nothing = return ()

formatLine :: String -> String -> String
formatLine category items = category ++ " " ++ items ++ "\n"

--printValues :: ItemsRegistry -> [IO ()]
--printValues l = [ v >>= putStrLn . show | (k,v) <- Map.toList l]
```

When running the above I can't figure out why it asks me for input category A before B since I used a foldl ? Seems like there is some lexical ordering behind it but I can't understand why.

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to your question, I strongly recommend beginners not use type aliases. They don't provide type safety and rarely provide cleaner intuition into the meaning of code.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I keep it in mind. At first the function signature looked  overwhelming to me without aliases that's why I used it. I clearly understand that alias does'nt provide type safety though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map`s are ordered. That's why most of the functions that work on `Map k v`s have a `Ord k` constraint. I think, internally, they are kept as some sort of binary tree.  There is no reordering of execution, just reordering of data. If you want a "map-like" structure that stays in the order you want rather than being sorted, use association lists:

```
type Assoc k v = [(k, v)]
-- usually we don't use this alias; [(k, v)] is shorter and widely understood
```

In `Prelude`, you will find

```
lookup :: Eq a => k -> [(k, v)] -> Maybe v
```

and all other map-like operations can be implemented through basic list manipulation.

In your code, you should thus change:

```
type ItemRegistry = [(String, InputLine)]
```

---

Also, if you use `foldl` to write some function from lists to lists, it will reverse the order, generally. This is because

```
foldl c n [x, y, z] = c (foldl c n [x, y]) z
```

which says to do something with the last element before doing something with the rest of the list, while

```
foldr c n [x, y, z] = c x (foldr c n [x, y])
```

means to do something with the first element before processing the rest. If you are used to strict languages, this is backwards. In a lazy language, things on the "outside" of an expression "happen" first; in a strict language things on the "inside" happen first.

This was not a problem for `Map`, because `Map.insert` is unordered (as long as there are no duplicate keys); it doesn't matter in what order you insert keys into a `Map`, because the `Map` will always be sorted according to the `Ord` instance. It is, however, a problem for association lists, which preserve order. You should thus say:

```
getInput :: [String] -> ItemsRegistry
-- getInput = foldr (\category acc -> (category, insertCategory category) : acc) []
-- but that should really be
getInput = map (\category -> (category, insertCategory category))
-- which you can turn into
-- getInput = map ((,) <*> insertCategory)
-- if you want
```

---

Finally, your `writeLine` and `writeData` are questionable. Notice:

```
writeData path data_ = [ writeLine path k (Map.lookup k data_) |  k <- Map.keys data_ ]
```

`k` is definitely a key to `data_`, but `Map.lookup k data_ :: Maybe InputLine`. Why? It won't ever be `Nothing`. The same would happen for `Data.List.lookup`. This means you've done something wrong, and I'm sure it made you uncomfortable when you saw it, too. I see you band-aided it by making `writeLine` accept a `Maybe`, making it a no-op if it receives `Nothing`, but that's just dodgy.

If you were using `Map` (which you can't, really, as I've said), you would use this function, which turns a `Map` into an association list.

```
-- alias toAscList
Data.Map.assocs :: Map k a -> [(k, a)]
```

And you would say

```
writeData path data_ = [ writeLine path k v | (k, v) <- assocs data_ ]
```

(If you think this look inefficient, it isn't. The documentation for `assocs` says it is subject to list fusion, meaning that the intermediate `assocs data_` list that appears to be created here gets optimized out of existence.)

Of course, we already *have* an association list. This makes `writeData` even simpler:

```
-- do be careful; Map.insert clobbers duplicates, but (:)ing onto an association
-- list means duplicate keys are preserved
-- you'd need to run nubBy ((==) `on` fst) on data if that's an issue
-- *that* might be inefficient (O(n^2) in the length of data_)
writeData path data_ = [ writeLine path k v | (k, v) <- data_ ]
-- or even
-- writeData path = map (uncurry (writeLine path))
-- if you want to be confusing
-- writeData = map . uncurry . writeLine

writeLine :: String -> String -> InputLine -> IO ()
writeLine path category lines = do words <- lines
                                   appendFile path $ formatLine category $ unwords words
```

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer ! I clearly understand what was wrong now. "This means you've done something wrong, and I'm sure it made you uncomfortable when you saw it, too" you're absolutely right about it ^^.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Map.html) for Data.Map, `Map.keys` returns "all keys of the map in ascending order". (Recall that the `Map` type requires its keys to be of a type that's an instance of `Ord`.)

Since `"A"` comes before `"B"` in the natural order, I think your use of `Map.keys` is causing `writeData` to have the "ask for A" action before the "ask for B" one.

Comment: thanks Robin I was totally focus on the reading input part, clearly missing the point about writing data. Is it some kind of re-arranging execution order according to function combination performed by haskell here ? Could you guide me to a better approach here please ?

Comment: I hesitate to say what a "better approach" would be, especially since I did little more than skim your code, but one thing that occurs to me is that, since your map has a very simple relation between the keys and values, you could probably rewrite this using just lists rather than maps. (A Map is more efficient than a list mainly for looking things up by key, which I don't think you ever do.) Then by `map`ping over the list you preserve the order of the input. This is more or less off the top of my head so I might have overlooked something.